# kafka-console-producer and bash script

Tags: bash, apache-kafka

Want to send some message by bash script.

```
  bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties > zookeeper.log 2>&1 &
sleep 2

bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties > server.log 2>&1 &
sleep 2

#Create topic
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1 --topic $1
sleep 2

#Get topics list
echo "kafka has next topics:"
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181

#send message
echo "will send messages:"
bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $1 "test 1"
```

Kafka started well. And I can send message by the producer console

```
 bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $1 "test 1"
```

But I can't send message into bash script. How can I send it by bash script ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37):

Try doing this:

```
echo "test 1" | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $1
```

or this:

```
cat file.txt | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $1
```

Comment: For continuous input (ie, if some other process writes into a file), you can use: `tail -n +1 -f file.txt | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic $1`

Answer (score 12):

You can also do the the below. Ignore the sleep parameter.

```
for x in {1..100}; do echo $x; sleep 2; done | path/to/bin/kafka-console-producer --broker-list <brk:port> --topic <topic_name>
```

Answer (score 6):

This also works:

`bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic "my-topic" < file.txt`

Answer (score 5):

This might be helpful for some. I tried running @sereija's answer where the producing message was a JSON of the form:

```
{"value_1":"name", "value_2":"preferred programming language"},
```

and the parsing was not performed correctly. You need to use backslash `\` to execute @sereija's answer when the message to post in the queue has strings. Precisely, my code worked as follows:

```
echo {\"value_1\":\"name\", \"value_2\":\"preferred programming language\"} | bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic <topic-name>
```